# Require.js config file

Tags: requirejs

I am learning require.js. I have a problem here. I want to reference knockout.js in my project. but the full name (knockout-x-x-x.js) is too long. I want the name to be just ko like
define(['ko'], function(ko){});
my folder structure is like

```
Scripts
 - knockout-x-x-x.js
 - main.js (configuration file)
 - app
   - view
     - view.js
```

my configuration file is look like

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: '/Scripts',
  shim: {
    'jquery': { 'exports': 'jquery' },
    'ko': { 'exports': 'ko' }
  },
  paths: {
    "jquery": "/Scripts/jquery-2.0.1.min",
    "ko": "/Scripts/knockout-2.2.1",
  },
  priority: [
    'jquery'
  ]
});
```

i always get an error says the "Scripts/ko.js" can not be found.
Can someone tell me what I did wrong here?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the "-2.2.1" from filename and path?

Comment: where should I remove the -2.2.1? do you mean rename the file in the folder or change my require.js configuration file.

Comment: You could try that, but I think Rayweb's answer might be the source of your problem. I just find that removing version numbers makes my life less stressful.

Answer (score 0):

your baseUrl is /Scrips, however in your paths seccion the url path for Ko is

/Scripts/knockout2.1.1,

require works with relative paths so what is saying is that it could not find /Scripts/Scripts/ko, try in your path just using the file name. as the main ans the knockout file are at the same level.